# Javascript/HTML: how to reverse a function?

Tags: javascript, html

trying (and failing) to figure out a way to have this function toggle. so that once its been done if you do the mousewheel it goes back into an orb.

```
$('html').on ('mousewheel', function (e) {
    moveAside();
  });
  function moveAside(){
    pointPreparations = function(){};
    var amountOnLeft = Math.round(mappers.length/2);
    var amountOnRight = mappers.length-amountOnLeft;
    var spaceBetweenLeft = ctx.height/amountOnLeft;
    var spaceBetweenRight = ctx.height/amountOnRight;
    console.log("Space left: " + spaceBetweenLeft + ", right:" + spaceBetweenRight);
    for(var n = 0;n != mappers.length;n++){
      mappers[n].setSpeed(40);
      if(n < amountOnLeft){
        mappers[n].setDestination(new Point(30, (spaceBetweenLeft*n)+10, 300));
      }else{
        mappers[n].setDestination(new Point((ctx.width-30), (spaceBetweenRight*(n-amountOnLeft))+10, 300));
      }
    }
  }
```

if you need the full doc. 
view-source:http://ruegg.me/
(wasnt sure to classify this as JS or html.)

Comment: I hope you know that html and javascript are related but very different technologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had nothing better going on, so I decided to take a crack at this. The following is what I came up with:

```
var disacknowledgeUntil = 0; // ignore until time.now >= this variable's time
$('html').off('mousewheel'); // remove old handlers (needed for testing from console to override website's handler)
$('html').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (disacknowledgeUntil > currentTime) {
        console.log("Ignored.")
        void 0;
        return !1; // in case browser fails to acknowledge void 0 call.
    } else {
        disacknowledgeUntil = currentTime + 1250; // ignore scroll events for next 1.25 sec.
        // When I (Spencer) was testing this in Chrome, chrome would send multiple messages for a scroll event,
        // so to counter this, I put this in place to make sure scrolls are not processed multiple times.
    }
    console.log(e.originalEvent);
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
        // User scrolled up, so we'll reinitialize the orb.
        console.log("calling reinitialize");
        reinitializeMap(); // call reinit.
    } else {
        // user scrolled down, so break the orb and move the pieces to the side as a border.
        console.log("Calling moveAside");
        moveAside();
    }
    return !0;
});
```

This causes the handler to call *`reinitializeMap()`* when the page is scrolled up (thus causing the orb to reappear) and then it will call `moveAside()` when the user scrolls down.

`reinitializeMap()` is a function I added in that resets nearly everything so the orbs are redrawn as if the page was just freshly loaded:

```
var intervalMapper = window.setInterval(function(){ manageMappers(); draw();}, 30);
var intervalTitle = window.setInterval(function(){ manageTitle();}, 200); // increased time because of spastic blinking.
var pointPrepBackup = function(){};
var lastInit = new Date().getTime();
function reinitializeMap(){
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    if(currentTime-lastInit < 1500){
        console.log("Called within last 1.5 seconds!");
        return !1; // don't reinitialize unless it has been more than 1.5 seconds since last init.
    }
    lastInit = currentTime;
    clearInterval(intervalMapper);
    intervalMapper = setInterval(function(){ manageMappers(); draw();}, 30);
    maxPoints = 200;
    mappers = [];
    pointPreparations = function(){};
      pointPrepBackup = function(){};
    zDistance = 600;

    //Sphere messing around
    baseRadius = 100;
    amount = 20;

    //var middle = (((layers-1)/2)+1);
    sphereLength = 500;
    zPlacement = zDistance/2;
    yPlacement = ctx.height/2;
    xPlacement = ctx.width/2;

   // var spacingBetweenLayers = sphereLength/layers;
    sphereLocations = [];

    perimiter = 2*Math.PI*baseRadius;
    spacing = perimiter/amount;

    mappers = [];

    for(var n = 0; n != amount; n++){
      var ratioPerimiter = (n*spacing)/perimiter;
      var angle = ratioPerimiter*360;
      var pointLocation = getFurtherPoint(xPlacement, zPlacement, toRadians(angle), baseRadius);
      //sphereLocations.push(new Point(pointLocation.a, yPlacement, pointLocation.b));

      var zDifference = Math.abs(pointLocation.b - zPlacement);//Radius
      var thisPerimiter = 2*Math.PI*zDifference;
      console.log(thisPerimiter);
      for(var m =0; m != Math.round(thisPerimiter/spacing); m++){
        var coPerimiter = (m*spacing)/thisPerimiter;//Column Perimiter
        var coAngle = coPerimiter*360+90;
        var coPointLocation = getFurtherPoint(yPlacement, zPlacement, toRadians(coAngle), zDifference);
        sphereLocations.push(new Point(pointLocation.a, coPointLocation.a, coPointLocation.b));
      }
      /*for(var m =0; m != amount; m++){
        var coPerimiter = (m*spacing)/perimiter;//Column Perimiter
        var coAngle = coPerimiter*360;
        var coPointLocation = getFurtherPoint(yPlacement, zPlacement, toRadians(coAngle+angle), baseRadius);
        sphereLocations.push(new Point(xPlacement, coPointLocation.a, coPointLocation.b));
      }*/
    }
    //ANGLE X, ANGLE Y

    for(var n = 0; n != sphereLocations.length;n++){
      randomX = (Math.floor(Math.random() * ctx.width) + 1);
      randomY = (Math.floor(Math.random() * ctx.height) + 1);
      mappers.push(new Mapper(randomX, randomY, ((Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 0)), sphereLocations[n], 0));
    }

    x = ctx.width;

    // canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove'); // remove old event listener
    $('canvas').off();
    $('canvas').on('mousemove', function(evt) {
      x = evt.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    });

    pointPrepBackup = function(){
      for(var n = mappers.length -1; n >= 0;n--) {
        var mapper = mappers[n];
        var currentAngle = Math.atan2(mapper.getZ() - zPlacement, mapper.getX() - xPlacement);
        var currentDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((mapper.getZ()-zPlacement), 2)+Math.pow((mapper.getX()-xPlacement), 2));
        var newPoint = getFurtherPoint(xPlacement, zPlacement, currentAngle+getAngleAddition(), currentDistance);
        mapper.setDestination(new Point(newPoint.a, mapper.getY(), newPoint.b));
      }
    };

    pointPreparations = pointPrepBackup;

}
```

`reinitializeMap()` also has a preventative peudo-timer to prevent it from being called too frequently; however, I added that in before I added `disacknowledgeUntil` to the handler function. I think `lastInit` is unnecessary now that `disacknowledgeUntil` has been added, but I'll leave that to you to test.

For a full example of this working and the complete script I used, you can check out the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SpencerD/jmcrxjv5/3/

For best viewing of the results page, the following will display as a full-page: https://jsfiddle.net/SpencerD/jmcrxjv5/3/embedded/result/

If you wanted to make it so scrolling down a second time would cause the page to revert back to an orb, the code above would just need the following modification:

```
var disacknowledgeUntil = 0; // ignore until time.now >= this variable's time
var orbState = !0; // true (!0) if showing orb; false if not showing orb (showing side bars)
$('html').off('mousewheel'); // remove old handlers (needed for testing from console to override website's handler)
$('html').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (disacknowledgeUntil > currentTime) {
        console.log("Ignored.")
        void 0;
        return !1; // in case browser fails to acknowledge void 0 call.
    } else {
        disacknowledgeUntil = currentTime + 1250; // ignore scroll events for next 1.25 sec.
        // When I (Spencer) was testing this in Chrome, chrome would send multiple messages for a scroll event,
        // so to counter this, I put this in place to make sure scrolls are not processed multiple times.
    }
    console.log(e.originalEvent);
    if (!orbState) { // not showing orb right now
        console.log("calling reinitialize");
        reinitializeMap(); // call reinit to display orb
    } else { // showing orb right now
        console.log("Calling moveAside");
        moveAside(); // transition from orb to sidebars
    }

    orbState = !orbState; // toggle state

    return !0;
});
```

*I have not tested that code, but it should work as far as I can tell.*